# can devcontainer postStartCommand script be included in the codespaces prebuild

Tags: vscode-devcontainer

I have a script `./.devcontainer/postCreateCommand.sh` and is included in the `devcontainer.json` `postCreateCommand` key as follows:

```
  "postCreateCommand": "oryx build -p virtualenv_name=.venv --log-file /tmp/oryx-build.log --manifest-dir /tmp && ./.devcontainer/postCreateCommand.sh || echo 'Could not auto-build. Skipping.'",
```

and `postCreateCommand.sh` is like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

minikube start
```

I'm seeing that it runs, but when testing the continued running of `minikube start` by running `kubectl get pods`, I'm not seeing anything and have to re-run `minikube start`. I was wondering how to keep this process running.

EDIT: I'm seeing that it according to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/create-dev-container , there's a separate postStartCommand key that I would need for something like this since anything in postStartCommand will need to complete execution for the container to start. I was wondering if this can be included in the prebuild on github codespaces.

Thank you.